# Get the lowest price of 6 tables with the same product id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, inner-join

This is the structure of the tables:

```
Table1
product_code - product_price
100001 - 100

Table2
product_code - product_price
100001 - 200

Table3
product_code - product_price
100001 - 300

Table4
product_code - product_price
100001 - 400

Table5
product_code - product_price
100001 - 500

Table6
product_code - product_price
100001 - 600
```

This query is fine apparently

```
$price = DB::queryFirstRow("
select * from Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table6
where Table1.product_code = Table2.product_code AND Table1.product_code = 100001");
```

the price of the last table according to the order within the db

```
echo $price['product_price']; // 600 the price of the last table according to the order within the db
```

I try to order by lowest price to get 100 result

```
$price = DB::queryFirstRow("
select * from Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table6
where Table1.product_code = Table2.product_code AND Table1.product_code = 100001 ORDER BY product_price");
```

I get this error

```
// ERROR: Column 'product_price' in order clause is ambiguous
```

**Any ideas how to solve it, thank you very much in advance for all your help!**

Comment: I think the first thing for me is why you have multiple tables which seem to contain price data?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, they all have in common the columns product_code and product_price

Comment: My comment is more about why you don't have 1 table with the various prices, with some form of price_type column (for example).  This would be a much more normalized table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you use `SELECT *` mysql will load all fields of all tables in from and joins.
Same name field in MySQL tables overwrite each other, then mysql will return only the field of last table (it's Table6 in you query).
if you do that query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT * FROM `Table3` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT * FROM `Table4` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT * FROM `Table5` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT * FROM `Table5` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
```

Mysql will return (not exact in that order):

```
product_code - product_price
100001 - 100
100001 - 200
100001 - 300
100001 - 400
100001 - 500
100001 - 600
```

You can add a `ORDER BY product_price ASC LIMIT 1;` or `DESC` if you want.

But do it only if you are studing, on a real application same name in fields of diferent tables is unrecommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use UNION statements to get all the prices and then you can sort and take the first result as the lowest price:

```
SELECT `product_price` FROM `Table1` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT `product_price` FROM `Table2` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT `product_price` FROM `Table3` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT `product_price` FROM `Table4` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT `product_price` FROM `Table5` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
UNION SELECT `product_price` FROM `Table5` WHERE `product_code` = 100001
ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1;
```